# nuget: should I commit the entire content of packages folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

I started using **nuget** and installed some packages, most of them have about **200 KB** max but **NUnit has 3MB**.

My solution is open-source and it is downloaded by lots of people, I'm just thinking: should I commit the entire packages folder as is or ignore non dll files

how do you guys do ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Personally I'd include the entire packages folder. There's nothing worse than getting an open-source project then having to hunt down the dll's needed to run it.

You could just include the .nupkg files and get the user to run update-package but then you are assuming they have nuget install and remember to run it.

I think its much quicker to get going of the open-source project has everything from the get go.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date. If you're reading this 2015 or later -> see Mark Heath's answer below!

Answer (score 88):

NuGet now has the ability for you to re-download the missing packages as a pre-build step, meaning that you only need to commit your packages.config file (and include nuget.exe in a tools folder).

Read [Using NuGet Without Committing Packages to Source Control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) for more details.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer these days. The accepted answer is out of date. If possible the OP should change the accepted answer to this one if he agrees.

Comment: @NickG I'm not sure there is a "correct answer" to this - it's a tradeoff (repository size vs ability to work in disconnected environments/certainty that dependencies cannot change or disappear). For me, the important thing is that the code builds successfully after a fresh get from source control and this technique works great while keeping the repo size small.

Comment: Website development in a disconnected environments? If that really happens then I don't want to work for that company.

Comment: The "correct answer" really depends on what you want. Working offline is one reason to include the packages, another is coping when packages you're dependent on are removed. The sad reality of software is sometimes you become dependent on old libraries that are no longer supported. If they disappear from nuget and you don't have a copy then you're a little screwed.

Comment: I don't know any "proper" website developers who could work with no internet access at all. Perhaps a graphic designer, but without access to the internet, Google and the online tools I use, I'd quickly get nowhere fast. I would say that this would be an edge case. I personally wouldn't even want to work without multiple monitors and definitely not from a laptop. I'd rather get another job.

Comment: While I am usually all about enabling offline work, and unrelated to whether or not this is a website project, I would expect a very temporary internet connection to exist when the open source project's code is first checked out from the repository. That is the right time to run NuGet's restore packages feature; after that all the necessary packages will be available offline in the working copy, even when working on the beach.

Comment: If you're working off-line… how did you download my code? o.o

Comment: @TwoWholeWorms You can always make a local, offline nuget repository using a regular Windows folder or use NuGet proxy like Klondike. See https://codurance.com/2015/05/04/creating-a-local-nuget-repository/

Answer (score 4):

To echo what Simon said -- it is 2010. Bandwidth and storage are cheap on that scale. The convenience of having the packages with the source beats the hell out of the savings.